# Adsense For A Job Board Site

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies, banners, monetize

I have a question regarding Adsense policies.I asked a similar question on the google Adsense forum and did not get a satisfactory reply, hence I am asking it here.

The thing is that I want to start a Job Board site.

The site will have listings of job along with recuitment date and vacancies and other relevant stuff.

As you can imagine my site will have some of the content that will be similar to other sites in the category. Meaning that if my site has a listing for a particular job there will be some other site with the same content.

If that happens can I get content strike by doing that?

Asking the same question on google forum for AdSense I got a reply saying that

> to be in the good books of Adsense the site must have content that
>   adds value to the user.

That to me is pretty vague.

The reply was from a reputed member of the forum.

So I replied by asking

> if that is the case then are a ton of site that are doing what I want
>   to do for years and years.

To which I got a reply saying that

> You would be risking you Adsense account if you do it. The people who
>   are doing this are walking a very thin line.

I want to ask the same question here. But also I want to ask that if such sites are "not adding any value" and hence "not AdSense worthy", they why is google not banning them.

Kindly provide some info in this regard along with links to more information if possible.

**PS:**
I am well aware of copyright and plagiarism that goes on in the web world and I do not wish to create yet another site that does that.

The purpose why I want to venture in this niche is because the sites that exist for my country are **beyond terrible** and are created by non-coders(yet they have no issue with Adsense). Hence, I want to provide a better user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your website would be adding value through:

(a) the aggregation of relevant content snippets from many sources;

(b) the reformatting of content for easy reading

Just be sure to attribute content to their sources and check you are not breaking any terms of use/licenses or infringing copyright.

You could also consider enabling recruiters to post job adverts to your site directly so you add value through the provision of content not available elsewhere.

Comment: Furthermore, there may be cases where the post content will not be lengthy, as you can imagine there might not be much subject matter as I will be posting details about a job. Will that be an issue?

Comment: Ideally you want to avoid pages with minimal content, so if you have some job adverts with loads of details that warrants its own page for more details, but you also have some job adverts that have only minimal details, then if you have a grid/list view of the job adverts (perhaps showing 20 on a page with pagination back and next links etc), try and show all the minimal version of the details in that view, only providing a link to a full page with additional details for those adverts that justify it. Include action buttons such as Apply Now or Add to Favourites in the grid/list view.

Answer (score 1):

A review of the Google [AdSense Program Policy](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=en#expand) does not indicate that this would be an issue. The only mention that even comes close to duplicate content is that sites may not contain copyrighted materials which based on your question won't be an issue for your site.

The important rule to follow is that your site should provide valuable content and service to your users which a job listings site most certainly would.

Answer (score 1):

If you have real users who value your website then you will not have any problems. I run a niche website that publish content that is also available on many other websites and successfully run adsense for years. The way how information is organised, search functions, etc - all this can create a "value". But I have real users from direct and organic traffic sources and have never had problems with my account.

Just don't try to fool google, don't buy shady traffic, be honest with your users, don't play bad games with ads and advertisers and you'll be alright.